# Why does scrollTop property of element stay 0 when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to use the `scrollTop` property in a project.

But it doesn't matter what I do: It always returns me `0`. I've working with Chrome. Tried Firefox too with the same result.

I have made this demo:

```js
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');

wrap.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 var sub = document.querySelector('.sub');

 console.log(sub.scrollTop); 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white; }

.wrap {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll; }

.sub {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(orange, green, blue, red); }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

[image: In Chrome]

**What do I wrong?**

Respectively: **Why do I get these obviously wrong value back?** 
I would expect approximately `800` when it is scrolled to the very bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scrollTop` property should be read from the actual scrolling element, `.wrap` in your case, not a child of that element.

Instead of:

```
console.log(sub.scrollTop);
```

Try:

```
console.log(wrap.scrollTop);
```